# Entity-Relationship Diagram Software

Tags: database-design, erd, tools

I saw this E-R diagram in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13103759) on Stack Overflow:

[image: Diagram]

Does anyone know which software was used to create it?

I use LucidChart but that output is really nice!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps unsurprisingly, you're not the first person to be intrigued by the fancy, fancy pictures in that post. If you look at the comments section below, you can see user [`@dangerousdave`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/261184/dangerousdave) asks...

> nice diagram, what tool did you use?

...to which the poster [`@joel-brown`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/659653/joel-brown) replies...

> ... I use [Visio](https://products.office.com/en-gb/visio/flowchart-software) with custom smart shapes that I built to use the James Martin ERD visual convention and a custom line pattern that gives it a hand-drawn look.

You might try reaching out to Joel at his public contact info and asking if he's willing to share the extensions he used <sup>(although the original post is around ~6 years old at the time of this writing so don't be too disappointed if he's using something else by now)</sup>.